# Полная информация о массиве и его данных

Tags: javascript

- Как узнать есть ли массив полноценным массивом, а не строкой или каким-либо "недомассивом"?

Я ожидал какой-либо функции `var_dump` как в PHP, но в JS я не могу понять какого типа данные массива и как вообще определить что массив настоящий и к нему можно будет использовать стандартные методы работы с массивами.

- Как узнать тип переменной массива и изменить на другой?

Мой массив хранит тысячи данных, но они частично модерируются в процессе скрипта и возможно их тип был изменен из-за этого. Есть какой-то способ узнать тип данных и изменить его на требуемый?

Comment: console.log, typeof не?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как узнать есть ли массив полноценным массивом, а не строкой или каким-либо "недомассивом"?

Не знаю, что такое "недомассив", но проверить, является ли объект массивом или нет можно с помощью метода [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

> Я ожидал какой-либо функции var_dump как в PHP

Аналог функции `var_dump()` из PHP в JavaScript - это [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/log). Результат отобразится в консоли браузера, которая открывается по нажатию комбинации клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

> Как узнать тип переменной массива

Для определения типа переменной используется оператор [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) или, как верно подметили в комментариях, [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof). Обратите внимание на то, что при проверке через [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) обычные объекты и массивы в JavaScript имеют один тип - `object`. Для идентификации массива можно использовать названный выше метод [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) или тот же [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

Comment: для проверки лучше `instanceof`

Comment: я подозреваю что "недомассив" это NodeList и прочие массивоподобные environment objects

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, по сути это любой объект со свойством length и числовыми ключами

Comment: `console.log()` вроде как не выдает информации про тип данных в массиве. `var_dump` говорит тип данных, в придачу к листингу массива.

Comment: @Grundy наверное так и есть. Я нашел это слово в английской версии портала и решил что это может быть достаточно понятно для описания текущего вопроса.

Comment: @Levelleor, `console.log`/`console.dir` вполне могут выдавать данные. Отличие в том, что они в консоль выводят, а не в разметку как var_dump. Ну и на самом деле какая разница какой реальный тип у объекта? если он ведет себя как как массив и у него есть методы массива - значит это массив

Comment: @Grundy что бы дебажить. Я использую библиотеку в которую нужно вводить именно массив, в котором еще массивы и все значения должны быть `int` иначе выдает ошибку типа данных. Я перепробовал много вариантов, но не работает и решил что нужно попробовать проверить что же не так, начал искать причину проблемы. А оказалось причину не так просто найти. На счет `console.log` мне выводит только значения, но не говорит их тип, использую Chrome. И последнее. Как изменить тип данных в int? Я так понял `parseInt`?

Comment: @Levelleor _Как изменить тип данных в int?_ - просто присвоить элементу новое значение

Comment: @Grundy ну к примеру у меня есть arr[5] = "5", это будет строка, что бы изменить тип данных мне нельзя просто переприсвоить строку. Или как?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50316/discussion-between-grundy-and-levelleor).